# Framer Motion animation repeats on state change

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I am building a task manager with React and Framer Motion. I'm animating a slide in transition for a react Portal / modal. The portal has a form in it with multiple input text fields in it, each with their own onChange handlers. However, whenever the onChange handler is called, the animation replays itself. I'm not sure what is the issue.

I've tried to add a repeat value of 0 to the transitions, but there seems to be no change. I'm pretty new to framer motion, so please let me what other details I need to provide.

Comment: It's hard to say what's going wrong without seeing any code. Can you post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what you're doing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `animate` prop, the component will animate on each render, this is useful only for simple cases, where the component typically renders once on the page. But in your case, this prop will not work since the input field re-renders on each change.

For your use case, it's better to use `useAnimation()` hook and pass the `animationControl` as `variant` prop and fire it manually on the first render only.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (firstRender) {
    animationControl.start();
  }
}, [])
```